# What differences between QPhongMaterial and QPhongAlphaMaterial?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt3d

I try to draw transparent QSphereMesh over two triangles. If I use with my sphere QPhongMaterial, then it works fine. But if I use QPhongAlphaMaterial, then sphere is drawn over first triangle, but under second.

So I don't understand what option I can set to change this behavior.

More detail about my problem you can read here: [Qt3d. Draw transparent QSphereMesh over triangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55001233/qt3d-draw-transparent-qspheremesh-over-triangles)

Comment: These two topics are connected. Here i try to resolve my problem more locally, than in topic i noticed.